# Rails & Devise - Autologin Across Subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise, rails-postgresql

### Setup

I have a Rails application where users register for an account, and a subdomain is created for them.  They can then proceed to the subdomain and log in with their credentials.  The workflow looks something like this:

1. User visits base domain fills out a form that with email/username/password and subdomain fields
2. From the submitted info, the server creates an account in the global/public database.  Server then creates a database that will be specific to that particular subdomain/account, and stores the user record in it.
3. **User is redirected to their subdomain, and asked to log in.**

(note: to implement the separate "databases", I'm using postgres schemas, but that should be irrelevant.)

### The question

My question involves step 3.  I would like to redirect the user to their subdomain and log them in automatically instead of asking them to log in.  However, I **do not** want to share a single session across all of the subdomains.

I would like to somehow securely transmit auto login request.

### Possible Solution

I have considered using a single-use, random token that I would store in a cookie and in the `users` table.  After the user successfully creates an account, he would be redirected to the subdomain.  At that point the token would be consumed/destroyed and the user would be automatically logged in.

I would also need to have a short window for the token to be used before expiring.

Thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue, the possible solution you suggest does not work because the session is not shared between subdomains.

I solved it the following way (same idea you propossed, different implementation):

- Create a new model (I called it LoginKey) that contains the user_id and a random SHA1 key.
- When the user is authenticated at the parent domain (for example: mydomain.com/users/sign_in), a new LoginKey is created and the user is redirected to the corresponding subdomain to an action that I called login_with_key (for example: user_subdomain.mydomain.com/users/login_with_key?key=f6bb001ca50709efb22ba9b897d928086cb5d755322a3278f69be4d4daf54bbb)
- Automatically log the user in with the key provided:

  key = LoginKey.find_by_login_key(params[:key])

  sign_in(key.user) unless key.nil?
- Destroy the key:

  key.destroy

I didn't like this solution 100%, I tried out a lot of different approaches that do not require a db record to be created, but always faced security concerns, and I think this one is safe.

Comment: I was suggesting using simply a cookie, which would be set to the root domain of the site (so it would be shared across subdomains).  Anyway, I'm accepting -- thanks for the help.

Comment: I had the exact same problem I was trying to solve and this seems to work. Sadly I posted the same question with a bounty, if you want to answer it it's all yours. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318870/using-devise-to-auto-login-a-user-on-a-multi-tenancy-site-with-subdomains