# Using Devise to auto login a user on a multi tenancy site with subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my app a customer registers on mysite.com. Once registration is complete, they are given a site such as customer.mysite.com. I'm using Devise and would like to log the customer into their site immediately. I'm using multitenancy as explained in the [RailsCast here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/388-multitenancy-with-scopes). I'm not quite sure how to go about this. The standard solution of adding sign_in to an after_sign_up_path_for def isn't working. I'm assuming it's trying to log the customer into mysite.com, not customer.mysite.com. I'm including my after_sign_up_path_for def so you can see what I'm trying with no success. The resource in my Devise implementation is User and a user has a Site.

RegistrationsController:

```
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    # Site.current_id = resource.site.id
    sign_in resource, bypass: true
    "http://#{resource.site.host}.#{ENV['BASE_HOST']}/sites/#{resource.site.id}/edit"
    # edit_site_url
  end
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue and solved it the following way:

Create a new model (I called it LoginKey) that contains the user_id and a random SHA1 key.
When the user is authenticated at the parent domain (for example: mydomain.com/users/sign_in), a new LoginKey is created and the user is redirected to the corresponding subdomain to an action that I called login_with_key (for example: user_subdomain.mydomain.com/users/login_with_key?key=f6bb001ca50709efb22ba9b897d928086cb5d755322a3278f69be4d4daf54bbb)
Automatically log the user in with the key provided:

key = LoginKey.find_by_login_key(params[:key])

sign_in(key.user) unless key.nil?

Destroy the key:

key.destroy

I didn't like this solution 100%, I tried out a lot of different approaches that do not require a db record to be created, but always faced security concerns, and I think this one is safe.

Comment: This worked great for me, thanks! Pretty simple to implement too.